# SSL not work in PHP5.6 on Windows

Tags: php, windows, ssl

I tried:

```
$host = 'ssl://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net';
$port = 443;

$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
    var_dump($errno, $errstr);
} else {
    echo 'Connected';
}
```

And:

```
$host = 'ssl://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net:443';

$fp = stream_socket_client($host, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
    var_dump($errno, $errstr);
} else {
    echo 'Connected';
}
```

But both returns:

```
int(0)
string(0) ""
```

As if I had not been able to connect.

- I tried PHP5.6 for x86 and PHP5.6 for x64
- I used lastet release in http://windows.php.net/download#php-5.6
- In Linux it seems to work normally.
- This only occurs with some fields, others work well.
- PHP with CURL and SSL work fine in PHP5.6

**Note:** Strangely in php5.4 works perfectly.

Is a bug in this version of PHP?

### Details:

PHP 5.4.12

> Registered Stream Socket Transports: tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
>
> Compiler: MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
>
> Architecture: x64
>
> Configure Command (compile):
>
> ```
> cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-embed" "--enable-cli-win32" "--enable-apache2-2handler" "--enable-apache2-2filter" "--enable-apache2-4handler" "--with-mysql=shared" "--with-mysqli=shared" "--enable-pdo" "--with-pdo-mysql=shared" "--with-pgsql=shared" "--with-pdo-pgsql=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--with-openssl=shared" "--enable-sockets=shared" "--enable-intl=shared" "--enable-mbstring=shared" "--enable-mbregex" "--enable-exif=shared" "--with-xmlrpc=shared" "--with-xsl=shared" "--enable-solr=shared" "--enable-solr-debug" "--with-curl=shared" "--with-tidy=shared" "--with-bz2=shared" "--enable-rar=shared" "--enable-fileinfo=shared" "--with-gettext=shared" "--with-mhash" "--with-ldap=shared" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--enable-soap=shared" "--enable-shmop=shared" "--with-gmp=shared" "--with-interbase=shared" "--with-pdo-firebird=shared" "--with-sqlite3=shared" "--with-pdo-sqlite=shared" "--with-pdo-odbc=shared" "--enable-dbase=shared" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_10_2\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_10_2\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_11_2\sdk,shared" "--with-sybase-ct=shared" "--enable-couchdb=shared" "--with-couchbase=shared" "--enable-mongo=shared" "--with-imap=shared" "--enable-mailparse=shared" "--enable-pop3=shared" "--with-smtp=shared" "--with-oauth=shared" "--with-ssh2=shared" "--with-snmp=shared" "--enable-uploadprogress=shared" "--enable-http=shared" "--with-imagick=shared" "--enable-discount=shared" "--with-pdflib=shared" "--with-haru=shared" "--with-excel=shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-printer=shared" "--with-geoip=shared" "--enable-timezonedb=shared" "--with-xdebug=shared" "--enable-suhosin=shared" "--disable-optimizer-plus" "--enable-pthreads=shared" "--enable-pthreads=shared" "--enable-win32service=shared" "--with-memcached=shared" "--enable-memcache=shared" "--enable-apc=shared" "--enable-apc-srwlock-native" "--enable-apc-debug" "--enable-xcache=shared" "--enable-xcache-optimizer" "--enable-xcache-coverager" "--enable-eaccelerator=shared" "--enable-varnish=shared" "--enable-ffmpeg=shared" "--disable-security-flags"
> ```
>
> **openssl**
>
> OpenSSL support: enabled
>
> OpenSSL Library Version: OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
>
> OpenSSL Header Version:  OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

PHP 5.6.26

> Registered Stream Socket Transports: tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
>
> Compiler: MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
>
> Architecture: x64
>
> Configure Command (compile):
>
> ```
> cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
> ```
>
> **openssl**
>
> OpenSSL support: enabled
>
> OpenSSL Library Version: OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
>
> OpenSSL Header Version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t 3 May 2016
>
> Openssl default config: c:/openssl-1.0.1c-X64/ssl/openssl.cnf
>
> openssl.cafile: no value
>
> openssl.capath: no value

Comment: Do you have the `php_openssl` extension enabled in ALL these versions of PHP, it may not be by default

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, it was like I said, only fails with some urls, other SSL domains work fine.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I update question with details from phpinfo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even PHP5.5 certificates works in a way in PHP, but after the PHP5.6 that has changed, as described in: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php

All encrypted client streams now enable peer verification by default. By default, this will use OpenSSL's default CA bundle to verify the peer certificate. In most cases, no changes will need to be made to communicate with servers with valid SSL certificates, as distributors generally configure OpenSSL to use known good CA bundles.

The default CA bundle may be overridden on a global basis by setting either the `openssl.cafile` or `openssl.capath` configuration setting, or on a per request basis by using the cafile or capath context options.

While not recommended in general, it is possible to disable peer certificate verification for a request by setting the verify_peer context option to `FALSE`, and to disable peer name validation by setting the `verify_peer_name` context option to `FALSE`.

The `fsockopen` try resolve connection using *cafile*, if php.ini is not configured, this show error `0`. You can try two solutions:

1. **Configure php.ini:**

   You can download https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and configure php.ini like this:

   ```
   openssl.cafile= "‪C:\openssl\cert\cacert.pem"
   ```

   > Maybe you need restart Apache/Ngnix
2. **Setup in execution time:**

   Setup `fsockopen` is possible, but you can use `fopen`+`stream_context_create`, or use `stream_socket_client`.

   > Note: sometimes the servers block functions like fopen and file_get_contents of access urls

   Example:

   ```
   <?php

   $opts = array(
       'ssl' => array(
           'verify_peer'   => true,
           'cafile'        => 'C:/openssl/cert/cacert.pem',
           'verify_depth'  => 5,
           'CN_match'      => 'fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net'
       )
   );

   $context = stream_context_create($opts);

   $host = 'ssl://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net:443';

   $fp = stream_socket_client($host, $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);

   if (!$fp) {
       var_dump($errno, $errstr);
   } else {
       echo 'Connected';
   }
   ```

   If you decide you need to disable checking for any reason, you can simply do this:

   ```
   <?php

   $host = 'ssl://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net';
   $port = '443';

   $opts = array(
       'ssl' => array(
           'verify_peer' => false
       )
   );

   $context = stream_context_create($opts);

   $host = 'ssl://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net:443';

   $fp = stream_socket_client($host, $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);

   if (!$fp) {
       var_dump($errno, $errstr);
   } else {
       echo 'Connected';
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/stream_socket_client

> If the value returned in `errno` is `0` and the function returned `FALSE`, it is an indication that the error occurred before the [system-level] `connect()` call. This is most likely due to a problem initializing the socket.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I'd check the output of `phpinfo()` on both installations to confirm that.